# Edit Cells in Excel from Outlook without reopening Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I would like to edit cells in Excel from Outlook using VBA.

I would like it so that:
The first time I run the macro, Cell A1 is "1".
The second time I run the macro, Cell A2 is "1".
The third time I run the macro, Cell A3 is "1".
.
.
When I run the macro the fifth time, it turns back to Cell A1 and increases cell A1's value from "1" to "2".

```
Dim count As Integer: count = 1
Dim number As Integer: number = 1

Sub test()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    If (IsWorkBookOpen("D:\Book1.xlsx") = True) Then     'Check workbook is opening or not
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks("D:\Book1.xlsx")
    Else
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\Book1.xlsx")
    End If

    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    If (count < 5) Then
        xlSheet.Range("A" & count) = number
        count = count + 1
    Else
        count = 0
        number = number + 1
    End If

End Sub


Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

It says "subscript out of range". I have a problem with this line: `Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks("D:\Book1.xlsx")`. When I debug I see this line highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because with `Workbooks(...)` you are implicitly using [`Item()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196016.aspx) property of `Workbooks` object which requires the *name or index number of the object*, while you are givin it the full name with path

use

```
Set xlWB = xlApp.workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
```

Comment: Owesome, It's run. Thank you so much :)